# Making a graph diagram in a web page

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm making a webpage with a lot of mathematics in it.  It currently uses MathJax to produce equations, but I also need to produce diagrams, like this one:

[image]

I could produce the images in some kind of external editor like LaTeX and then insert them in the page, but this has disadvantages:

1) Managing lots of image files.
2) Not maximally accessible. For instance, if the information were produced by some kind of Tikz code, people might be able to search or get some kind of information from the code being included in the page.  By merely embedding an image it ceases to become searchable or readable anything other than eyeballs.

I could produce this inside of a canvas element but that has disadvantages:

1) Time-consuming to produce the diagrams, and I'll be making a very large number of them.
2) Slows rendering for people on mobile connections.

If these are my options then I'll probably just do it in a canvas element.  But are there any options I'm not considering, which might have fewer disadvantages?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for stack overflow unless you have tried something and it didn't work. Asking for general guidance is off-topic since there could be multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

latex.js is a good option as well, it's 100% JS.
https://latex.js.org/playground.html

Comment: So I don't know much about how to use these tools and am currently hitting a roadblock with setting up LaTeX.js.  Do you know if there is some place where I can find a tutor or freelancer who can help me set this up?